# How to use firebase query in actions-on-google

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google

I want to use firebase query to search for a particular user by their name in my action-on-google app.I have used the following code but it dosen't prints anything.

```
const ref = firebase.database();
const nm = ref.child('Users');
const q = 
nm.orderByChild('Name').equalTo('abcd');
q.on('value', snap => {
conv.ask(snap.val());
});
});
```

Can somebody help in rectifying my code.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Javascript is pretty asynchronous, meaning that you need to make sure that your function understands the flow of your execution and more importantly know when it ends.

The standard way of doing this is through a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Many async functions now return Promises.

So you can rewrite your code as:

```
app.intent('intent name', conv => {
    const ref = firebase.database();
    const nm = ref.child('Users');
    const q = nm.orderByChild('Name').equalTo('abcd');
    return q.once('value', snap => {
        conv.ask(snap.val());
    });
});
```